# post to self textarea blank

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

I've been looking through the site and going over pointers on similar problems but none have seemed to work for me. I'm a wee bit stuck, hoping someone can point out my stupidity.

I created a basic form to test as my main site was giving me problems. There is no error checking or filtering for malicious code, it's just a test to figure out why it won't work.
I can't retrieve any data from a textarea.
All other types work, text, number, etc... all fine.

Here is my basic form, can anyone see the error of my ways?

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    echo "<br>single line comment: " .$_POST['singlelinecomment'];

    if (!isset($_POST['comments']))
    {
        echo "<br>nothing in textarea data, move along, move along";
    }
    else
    {
        $comments = $_POST['comments'];
        echo "<br>comments: ". $comments;
    }
}
?>
<form name="conversation-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name="singlelinecomment">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="20" cols="50" form="conversation-form" name="comments"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: good debugging tool: `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form="conversation-form"` remove it from textarea, it's the main cause.

*Plus*, you don't need this `name="conversation-form"` in `<form>`, *unless* you want to use it for CSS purposes, *then* use `id="conversation-form"` or `class="conversation-form"`

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="50" form="conversation-form" name="comments"></textarea>
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ remove it
```

---

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name="singlelinecomment">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="20" cols="50" name="comments"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: ohh wow, that simple. thanks so much.
i added it in as a suggestion that fixed someone else's problem.